# Should I update my spoilers?

Tags: discussion, spoilers

I have an answer for [What does the ending for Dark Souls 2 mean?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/169501/what-does-the-ending-to-dark-souls-2-mean/169539#169539), which is effectively one giant spoiler. However, 1 year later, the ending is pretty much common knowledge, so I was wondering whether or not I should/could remove the spoiler formatting? Or is that my perogative?

Comment: Spoilers are a rather contentious topic.  The basic process we follow is that if someone is asking something, directly answer the question.  Supplemental information can be in spoiler tags, but are not required.  If you're spoilering the whole answer, you're doing it wrong.  That answer should never have been spoilered in the first place.

Comment: One could argue that if you click on a question titled " what does the ending for [game] mean?", then you have agreed to see spoilers, because you can't answer a question like that without spoiling the ending.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are no rules for the use of spoilers on Arqade. Use your judgement. In general, if everything in your post, whether it be a question or an answer, then *nothing* is a spoiler, because it's impossible to determine what's behind that mouseover without the context of a broader answer.

Comment: If you don't ask, you'll never know. Thanks. This does make sense - an answer that is entirely spoilers isn't an answer, and if someone asked, they *want to know*.